# Azure Event Hubs Capture to Storage with Data Lake Gen2 enabled

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-eventhub

I'm trying to use the Capture feature of Event Hubs to store in a Storage Account v2 with Data Lake Storage Gen2 enabled.
In the portal, after choosing the Storage Account, the containers don't show up and I can't create a new one.
In Azure CLI, I ran the following command:

```
az eventhubs eventhub update -n hubtest --namespace-name #removed# -g #removed# --enable-capture True --capture-interval 300 --capture-size-limit 262144000 --storage-account #removed# --blob-container #removed# --destination-name capturetest
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'enabled'
Traceback (most recent call last):File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/knack/cli.py", line 206, in invoke cmd_result = self.invocation.execute(args)
File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 328, in execute raise ex
File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 386, in _run_jobs_serially results.append(self._run_job(expanded_arg, cmd_copy
File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 379, in _run_job six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise raise value
File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 356, in _run_job result = cmd_copy(params)
File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 171, in __call__ return self.handler(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/arm.py", line 477, in handler instance = custom_function(instance=instance, **custom_func_args)
File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/eventhubs/custom.py", line 112, in cli_eheventhub_update instance.capture_description.enabled = enabled
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'enabled'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue, it seems not support to enable Azure Event Hubs Capture with Data Lake Gen2, remember the  Data Lake Gen2 is in preview.

See this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-upgrade?toc=%2fazure%2fstorage%2fblobs%2ftoc.json#azure-ecosystem

[image]

Comment: @fbdntm I am not sure, you may need to contact azure team for this information.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have *first created* your Azure Storage account with **Data Lake Storage Gen2** - see the image from the portal below:

[Enable Data Lake Storage Gen2 on storage account]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/J55kC.png

You can then just use 'Azure Storage' as the capture provider and proceed to select the storage account container - see the image from the portal below:
[storage account selection]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhI1x.png

**Note***
If you don't already have a container configured, you will be asked to do so as part of the selection process steps.

*Bit of an old question I know, but I needed to do just that today. Hope it helps.*

**Reference**:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-capture-enable-through-portal

Answer (score 0):

[Event Hub Capture is now supported on Azure Data Lake Storage Gen 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-capture-enable-through-portal)